# Angular 1.5 promise returns object object instead of data using Grails 3.2 Angular Profile

Tags: angularjs, grails

Banging my head too long on this, can't see what I am missing in order to convert promise to actual data. User picks country which fires change event which is calling service API (data confirmed returned), the only thing left is getting the actual data returned which then sets the value in another control.

Controller Code (Relevant)

```
angular  //1.5
    .module("fytrnlt.fybkbra")

    //create new factory section

    .factory('myAPIService', function ($resource, $http, $q) {
        var service = {};

        service.GetNextBranchCode = function (VParm) {

            console.log('service.update fired received parameter value of ' + [VParm]);

            var FResult = $resource("/api/fireFunc1/" + [VParm]);

            return FResult.get().$promise.then(function (data) {
                console.log('get fired')

                return data
            })

        };
```

UPDATED CODE TO TRY ANOTHER METHOD BUT YIELDS SAME RESULT

```
service.GetNextBranchCode2 = function (VParm) {

            console.log('service.GetNextBranchCode2 fired received parameter value of ' + [VParm]);

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            if ([VParm]) {
                // Resolve the deferred $q object before returning the promise
                 $http.get('/api/fireFunc1/'+ [VParm]).success(function (data) {

                    // Store your data or what ever....
                    // Then resolve
                    deferred.resolve(data);


                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.reject("Error: request returned status " + status);
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            }

        };

        return service;

    })
    .controller("FybkbraCreateController", FybkbraCreateController);

function FybkbraCreateController(Fybkbra, $state, $stateParams, Fytrnlt, Fytbank, Stvnatn, $filter, myAPIService) {

    var vm = this;

   vm.GetNextBranchCode = function () {
       // myAPIService.GetNextBranchCode([vm.fybkbra.fytbank]).then(function (result) {
            //vm.FuncResults = result.data;
           // var FuncResults = result.data;

            //vm.fybkbra.fybkbrabranchcode = FuncResults.toString();

       // same result as above code, returns object not resolved data
            var promise = myAPIService.GetNextBranchCode([vm.fybkbra.fytbank]);
            promise.then(function(greeting) {
                alert('Success: ' + greeting);
            }, function(reason) {
                alert('Failed: ' + reason);
            }, function(update) {
                alert('Got notification: ' + update);
            });

        //});
    };
}
```

HTML Code - change event fires call to Restful Grails API resource

```
 <div class="fieldcontain required">
    <label for="fybkbrabankcode">Bank
      <span class="required-indicator">*</span>

    </label>
       <select required="" name="fytbank" ng-required="true" id="fytbank" ng-model="vm.fybkbra.fytbank" ng-change="vm.GetNextBranchCode()" ng-options="fytbank.id as (fytbank.id + ':' + fytbank.fytbankbanktitle ) for fytbank in vm.fytbankList"></select>
 </div>
  <div class="fieldcontain required">
    <label for="fybkbrabranchcode">Branch Code
      <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <input required="" name="fybkbrabranchcode" id="fybkbrabranchcode" ng-model="vm.fybkbra.fybkbrabranchcode" type="text" readonly />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to actually make the call of the promise, I guess.

```
var promise = myAPIService.GetNextBranchCode([vm.fybkbra.fytbank]);
promise().then(function(greeting) { // <- notice the brackets
    alert('Success: ' + greeting);
}, function(reason) {
    alert('Failed: ' + reason);
}, function(update) {
    alert('Got notification: ' + update);
});
```

Comment: Sorry can you give an example as I don't follow you. The code is fired by html change event which is confirmed from both the database trigger event log and outputting to intellij log window. I have now also tried the following code which as I understand it on a superfical level is supposed to resolve the promise but it is yielding the same result. Ironically I am able to do this in a POJO project but not from grails. See edited code which includes the other method I mentioned.

Comment: The issue was in the angular code:  myAPIService.GetNextBranchCode2([vm.fybkbra.fytbank]).then(
            function (result) {
                vm.fresult01 = result;

                vm.temp = angular.fromJson(vm.fresult01) 

                alert("Fetching next branch code into branch code field.")
                vm.fybkbra.fybkbrabranchcode = vm.temp.fresult01;



            },
            function (message) {
                alert(message);

            }
        )